# How do I fix this in R studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-analysis

I made a barplot using ggplot2 in R studio and for easy readability, I replaced the y-axis labels(containing values in thousands) with the suffix 'K'.

For e.g-if the y-axis label was '10000', I replaced it with '10K' and likewise.

The code:-

```r
full_data_cl %>% 
  group_by(month, rider_type) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_ride = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  filter(rider_type == 'casual') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = number_of_ride)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', colour = "black", fill = "darkorange") + 
    labs(title="No.of Rides Per Month") + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 0.1, size = 40, vjust = -5)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 15)) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 15)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.title = element_blank()) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = number_of_ride), size = 7, vjust = -1)
```

[image: Click here to view the original plot]

I included the following line in the code fiven above to make the necessary changes:-

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(suffix = "K",scale = 1e-5))
```

The code generated the following visualization:-
[image: Click here to view the modified plot]

As we can see the y-axis labels are reflecting the changes I made but the labels above the bars are still the same.

Can someone guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Because you haven’t modified the derivation of number_of_ride.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have a geom_text layer in your code. That will add in the layer with labels over your bars. Remove it and you should be good to go
Remove this line of your code
geom_text(aes(label = number_of_ride), size = 7, vjust = -1)

Comment: This would remove the labels completely. The thing is that I want my labels to reflect the changes too.
For e.g:- the first label shows the value "14614" and I want it to be shown as 14.6K and likewise.